# How to set different colors on matplotlib bar graph based on the group of data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have created this table:[image: table]

There are football players from every league whose overall rating is more than 80.

I also created a bar graph which looks like this:[image: graph]

Code I have written is this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.bar(grouped.short_name,grouped.overall)
plt.title("football players with 80+ rating")
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.ylabel("overall rating")
plt.show()
```

But I want the graph to have columns of different colors based on the league player represents.
For example: players from Seria A be Green, players from Bundesliga - Red and etc. I also want the graph to have legend which shows which color corresponds to which league.
How can I do this?

Comment: Could you perhaps post a raw version of a small sample of your data? Not in image format.

Comment: check out the existed so post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340415/matplotlib-bar-plot-add-legend-from-categories-dataframe-column and if you still can't figure out, post your data as @ItaiDagan mentions about.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `seaborn` and use the `hue` parameter. You need to make sure your player short names are unique.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = {'league_name':['A','A','A','B','C','C','C'],
        'club_name':['Club 1','Club 1', 'Club 1','Club 2', 'Club 3', 'Club 3', 'Club 3'],
        'short_name':['Joe','Jon','Jack','Ryan','Peter','Steve','Paul'],
        'overall':[83,88,87,90,87,93,81]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)




ax = sns.barplot(x='short_name', y='overall', data=df, hue='club_name', dodge=False)
plt.title("football players with 80+ rating")
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.ylabel("overall rating")
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the responses. After some research I came up with this answer:

```
import random
leagues=grouped.league_name.unique()
plt.figure(figsize=(14,5))
for l in leagues:
    rgb = (random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
    plt.bar(grouped[grouped.league_name==l].short_name,grouped[grouped.league_name==l].overall,color=[rgb],label=l)
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.title("players with 80+ rating")
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,1),fontsize=6)
    def value_labels(y):
        for i in range(len(y)):
            plt.text(i,round(y.iloc[i]),round(y.iloc[i]),size=7,ha="center",va="bottom",rotation=0)
    value_labels(grouped.overall)
plt.show()
```

Here is the result:

[image]

It comes with some kind of alert which I don't understand. I got the desired result though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet.

This code allows you to set random colors to your barplot.

```
for i in range(0, len(grouped.short_name)+1):
    l.append(tuple(np.random.choice(range(0, 2), size=3)))
      
plt.bar(grouped.short_name, grouped.overall, color=l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the list of bars when plotting the graph, then change the bar color according to the league name.

```
plt.figure()
bars = plt.bar(short_name, overall)

for i, bar in enumerate(bars):
    if "English" in league_name[i]:
        bar.set_color('r')

plt.show()
```